# Add if clause which checks if the url contains 'securepdf' in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, url

I am not well versed with JavaScript/JQuery and I am trying to make a particular wordpress plugin work this way:

The event must be fired when the URL on which the user clicks has the substring `securepdf/` in it. Example of such URL is: `http://igcse.net/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/2017/10/sample-phy.pdf` I just want to add the `if` statement in the code. Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Custom jQuery goes here
    $('[data-pdf]').click(function(event) {
        $('.pdfembedder_item').hide();  
        var id = $(this).data('pdf');   
        $('#'+id).show();
        jQuery('.pdfemb-viewer').pdfEmbedder();
    });
  });
```

This piece of code as far as I can understand renders a pdf by calling the `pdfEmbedder()` function when a user clicks on a URL. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the url with "indexOf", which will return the index of "/securepdf/" if it is on the url, or -1.

```
var url = document.location.pathname;
if (url.indexOf('/securepdf/') !== -1) {
    // there is securepdf on the url
} else {
    // there isn't securepdf on the url
}
```

It's good to remember that if you search only for "securepdf", without the slashes, you might get some urls that have securepdf scattered around the path (e.g. "http://(...)/notasecurepdf.html"), and not only that matches the criteria you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const url = 'http://igcse.net/wp-content/uploads/securepdf/2017/10/sample-';

console.log(url.includes('securepdf')); // true
```